# Own pages model not loading

Tags: model, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have extended the pages table and configured the TCA (works fine). Now I configured an extension class for the pages Model. This Model should work well, but gets ignored by TYPO3.

I have registered my own Model class via this TS Setup here, which also gets loaded in TS Object Browser, so it should work.

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            XY\XYSitetemplate\Domain\Model\Pages {
                mapping {
                    tableName = pages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even when I produce syntax error in my Model TYPO3 still ignored my own class. It's not getting loaded.

Also cleared the system cache in install toll, recreate autoload information and reinstalled the extension.

Comment: It shouldn't be loaded until it is needed, so perhaps it would be helpful if you add where/how you're trying to use this model

Comment: I am using the DCE extension. There is an fluid array `{page}`– and there I would like to use this data as modeled object (espacially my own two relation fields) so that I can directly access relationd and objects within the `{page}` array.

I now have tried to fetch the page data with an own ViewHelper via the PageRepository but I have no clou how to assign my own model to that fetched data.